# wxWidgets CMake Windows Setup Troubles

Tags: cmake, wxwidgets

I am really struggling to setup wxWidgets to work on Windows and CMake and would appreciate some help.

I have downloaded wxWidgets 3.1.4, run the setup (which extracted to `C:\CPP_lib\wxWidgets`) and then ran the following commands in the terminal:

```
cd C:\CPP_lib
mkdir wxWidgets-install
cmake C:\CPP_lib\wxWidgets -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\CPP_lib\wxWidgets-install -DwxBUILD_SHARED=OFF
cd wxWidgets-install
cmake --build . --target install
```

I have environment variables `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` set to `C:\CPP_lib` and `wxWidgets_DIR` and `wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR` both set to `C:\CPP_lib\wxWidgets-install`.

However, when I have a simple CMake project that calls `find_package(wxWidgets)`, I get the following message in the terminal:

```
Found wxWidgets: winmm;comctl32;uuid;oleacc;uxtheme;rpcrt4;shlwapi;version;wsock32
missing components: core base png tiff jpeg zlib regex expat
```

Please help - I have been struggling for a while now :(

Comment: If you build wxWidgets with `C:\CPP_lib\wxWidgets-install` installation prefix, you need to put exactly this prefix into `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable. As for the error message, it doesn't look as real one. Are you sure that you have got exactly this error message?

Comment: @GaeyAllen, which compiler do you use? If you are not planning to make wxWidgets a part of another project that already uses cmake-crap, I'd download MSVC Community and build the library with it. Really straightforward.

Comment: @Tsyvarev would I need to put the path to wxWidgets-install into CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, or simply the one to CPP_LIB? Also, this was definitely the message I received out of CMake in the terminal

Comment: @Igor I previously used Visual Studio, however would like my projects to be cross platform compatible. CMake seems like the main way of doing this (although if there is a workflow that works with Visual Studio I'd be all ears). Another reason that I use CMake, however, is due to it compatibility with VS Code (I prefer VS Code to Visual Studio)

Comment: "would I need to put the path to wxWidgets-install into CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, or simply the one to CPP_LIB?" - Setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is usually sufficient.

Comment: @GaryAllen, you can use MSVC on Windows and Xcode on OSX as those are native compilers on the platform and will generate a perfect, , very optimized platform code. On Linux, I'd use Anjuta, since wxWidgets is using GTK under the hood, and Anjuta is native GTK/GNOME IDE. The setup for all 3 environment is very straightforward. If you need more - ping me on the wx forum and I explain in details.

Comment: Besides you need to compile your code and the library on every platform anyway...

Comment: @Igor this involves setting up multiple projects with the exact same configurations - something CMake was infected invented for to solve. I will stick with CMake thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was a very specific one related to vcpkg.

I had pointed CMake to my vcpkg toolchain file (even though wxWidgets was installed independent of vcpkg) and this was causing issues with finding wxWidgets i.e. vcpkg was preventing wxWidgets (a non-vcpkg installation) from being found.

I believe this is a vcpkg bug, although am not sure, but have reported it anyways.